# IDEA warning - Could not autowire - no beans found

Tags: spring-boot

InteliJ IDEA presents this warning:

[image]

```
@Repository
class TaskRepository {
    // ...
}
```

The warning seems to be a false positive because the above code works fine (the repo class is injected into the use case)

I wonder whats the desired solution is here. Do I need another annotation together with the repo annotation?